# FCM credentials fail in firebase emulator

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to test push notifications through the firebase emulator i.e. locally. I am using cloud functions and calling the function directly.

Here are the steps:

1. Download admin key
   [image]
2. Set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`:

```
➜  Desktop export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=pearl-cef7c-4833cff1a093.json
```

3. Run the emulator via `firebase emulators:start`
4. Try calling an FCM function: `admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, message);` via a webhook.
5. Getting failure that `Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions.`

Why would my admin key fail? I have the same issue when I use Service Accounts!

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "push"
  {"structuredData":true,"severity":"INFO","message":"Hello logs!"}
i  functions: Finished "push" in ~1s
  /Users/me/Desktop/pearl-mobile/cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44
          var _this = _super.call(this, errorInfo.message) || this;
                             ^

  FirebaseMessagingError: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. Raw server response: "<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
  <H1>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</H1>
  <H2>Error 401</H2>
  </BODY>
  </HTML>
  ". Status code: 401.
      at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/me/Desktop/pearl-mobile/cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
      at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/me/Desktop/pearl-mobile/cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
      at new FirebaseMessagingError (/Users/me/Desktop/pearl-mobile/cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:279:16)
      at Object.createFirebaseError (/Users/me/Desktop/pearl-mobile/cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-errors-internal.js:57:12)
      at /Users/me/Desktop/pearl-mobile/cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request-internal.js:79:51
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    errorInfo: {
      code: 'messaging/authentication-error',
      message: 'An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. Raw server response: "<HTML>\n' +
        '<HEAD>\n' +
        '<TITLE>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</TITLE>\n' +
        '</HEAD>\n' +
        '<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n' +
        '<H1>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</H1>\n' +
        '<H2>Error 401</H2>\n' +
        '</BODY>\n' +
        '</HTML>\n' +
        '". Status code: 401.'
    },
    codePrefix: 'messaging'
  }

  Node.js v18.0.0
```

Comment: Please edit the question to share the complete minimal code that fails (not just the one line) along with the way you invoke it. We should be able to repro ourselves based on the instructions you give. Note that the technique of using process env vars to initialize the admin SDK would not work in Cloud Functions deployed to the actual cloud service - you would instead pass the credential directly to the SDK, or use dotenv, or use CLI env vars (which is a different thing). Read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Comment: Can you check Step 2 if your service account credential is properly set using this command `cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`